# Solving the given differential equation which was supposedly a simple first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I recently encountered the following question on my exam-

$$(\tan^{-1}y-x)dy=(1+y^2)dx$$

I have only been taught how to solve linear and first order differential equations.

My attempts included the following-

- Substitution using $y=\tan q$ and then trying to simplify as I observed the term in RHS would yield $\sec^2q
  $ post this substitution.
- I also tried to use the integrating factor method but the expression wasn't being simplified into a form where it could be used.

After a while I thought maybe it was a mistake and couldn't be solved at my level of understanding. Kindly help me evaluate the solution for this equation.

Comment: solve for x' instead of y'. It's easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$(\tan^{-1}y-x)dy=(1+y^2)dx$$
$$\implies (1+y^2)x'+x=\tan^{-1}y$$
Solve for x

Or rewrite it as:
$$(\tan^{-1}y-x)\frac {y'}{(1+y^2)}=1$$
$$(\tan^{-1}y-x)(\tan^{-1}y)'=1$$
$$(z-x)(z)'=1$$
$$x'=z-x$$

Answer (score 1):

The substitution $u = \tan^{-1}(y)-x$ and some simplification transforms this differential equation into
$$ u \;du  = (1 - u)\; dx $$
which is separable.

Comment: How did this substitution come into your mind? Is it due to practice and experience?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}(y)-x$ occurs in the equation.  First I tried $v = \tan^{-1}(y)$, then saw that $v-x$ would be better.

Comment: Ok thanks for the insight